# function to search for a pattern

Tags: search, functions, global-command

I just recently found a very nice command to search for a pattern in a document, and display all hits:

```
:g/pattern/z#.1
```

Since the command is a bit cumbersome to type, I would like to make a shortcut, so instead of typing the command above, I could simply type

```
:sl pattern
```

(`sl` stands for search & list, for lack of a better name.)

I wonder what is the best way to do this. I think one first needs to define a function

```
function! SearchList(pattern)
    f/a:pattern/z#.1
endfunction
```

But the only thing the function does, is to show its own content (since this is the only occurrence of `a:pattern` in my `.vimrc`.

So here I'm stuck. To create a mapping, is the function actually needed? Or what is the best way to define the mapping? And if indeed a function is the way to go, how would I write this function?

Comment: use `:exe ":g/".a:pattern."/z#.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a custom command line command [`:command`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#:command) is a good choice:

```
:command! -nargs=1 SL g/<args>/z#.1
```

You'll need to use a name that starts with a capital letter, though, so I'm using "SL" instead of "sl". Run with `:SL pattern`.

The rest is pretty self-explanatory. Use a bang (`!`) after `:command` to allow subsequent overrides (good for including it in your vimrc file). Specify number of args as 1. Insert that in the command to be run with `<args>`. BTW, with `-nargs=1` spaces are allowed in whatever comes after the command name (in our case the pattern) and it will still be considered one argument.

Comment: Nice! Extra points for `nargs=1`, which allows for whitespaces in the search pattern.

Comment: @pfnuesel Yes, someone was using their noggin when they designed that part of `:command`.  :) Cheers!